# Question about discontinuities of rational functions

Tags: calculus

I'm studying for my Calculus 1 final, and my teacher wrote that if $f(x)$ is a rational function defined as $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$, if $p(a) = 0 = q(a)$, then $p(x)$ MAY have a removable discontinuity at $x = a$. I don't understand why she emphasized that it "may" have one... are there instances where it does *not* have a removable discontinuity? In all of my example problems, when $p(a) = 0 = q(a)$, I have been able to find a common factor for the two functions (and that was my removable discontinuity).

Are there instances where that is not a removable discontinuity, or instances where you can't find a common factor at all? Or other ways where when $p(a) = 0 = q(a)$, there is no removable discontinuity?

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: What if $p(x)=x$, $q(x)=x^2$, and $a=0$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you so much for an example! But just a follow up question, if you have time: so the common factor would be x, but x = 0 is not a removable discontinuity. Honestly, I would have just believed it was. How could you tell it isn't, without graphing it? Thanks so much.

Comment: Use the fact that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac x{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac1x$, which does not exist.

Comment: The roots of $p$ and $q$ may have a *multiplicity* that is greater than $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an example take $p(x)=x$, $q(x)=x^2$, and $a=0$.

For a less trivial example take $p(x)=x^2 - 2x + 1$ (which equals $(x-1)^2$) and $q(x)=x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x - 1$ (which equals $(x-1)^3$), and $a=1$.

In general the number of $(x-a)$ factors in $q(x)$ may be strictly larger than the number of $(x-a)$ factors in $p(x)$, in which case the discontinuity is not removable.

Comment: That really helped! Thank you so much. It won't let me upvote because I'm a new user :( If you have time, just a quick clarification question:

So if there are more factors in the denominator than there are in the numerator, the discontinuity is not removable? But if there are more factors in the numerator than there are in the denominator, it is removable?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: By the way, as a new user you might not know, if you get an answer that you like you can click the "accept" button, to award the answerer with some reputation points.

Comment: I would definitely love to do that! But I don't see the "accept" button--I did a ctrl-F and it is not showing up. Where can I find it?

Comment: Take a look at [the tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), you should find an explanation there with pictures.

Comment: Done! Thanks so much again for the help.